# SQLAlchemy connect() attempts to connect to redundant db not part of connection url

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-utils

I've a pymysql sqlalchemy engine constructed using the `create_engine` method. The connection string in the `engine.url` field has the right parameters. Yet when I call `engine.connect()` it tries to connect to a different db and throws an OperationalError. The ip in the error message is different from the one in the connection string. I've tried clearing the pool with `engine.pool.dispose()`.

```
Engine.__dict__ prints:
{'pool': <sqlalchemy.pool.impl.QueuePool at 0x7f7c74038f70>,
 'url': mysql+pymysql://root:***@xx.xxx.xxx.155:3306/db_mart,
 'dialect': <sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.pymysql.MySQLDialect_pymysql at 0x7f7c75b3c2e0>,
 '_echo': None,
 'logger': <Logger sqlalchemy.engine.Engine (WARNING)>,
 'hide_parameters': False,
 '_compiled_cache': {},
 'dispatch': <sqlalchemy.event.base.ConnectionEventsDispatch at 0x7f7c74052580>}
```

Traceback when calling engine.connect():

```
OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'xxx.xx.xx.xx' (using password: YES)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

OperationalError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~/github-repos/compute_engine/compute_engine/engine/data_model.py in <module>
----> 1 engine.connect()

~/github-repos/dd_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in connect(self, close_with_result)
   3318         """
   3319 
-> 3320         return self._connection_cls(self, close_with_result=close_with_result)
   3321 
   3322     @util.deprecated(

~/github-repos/dd_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in __init__(self, engine, connection, close_with_result, _branch_from, _execution_options, _dispatch, _has_events, _allow_revalidate)
     94                 connection
     95                 if connection is not None
---> 96                 else engine.raw_connection()
     97             )
     98 

~/github-repos/dd_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in raw_connection(self, _connection)
   3397 
   3398         """
-> 3399         return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)
   3400 
   3401 

~/github-repos/dd_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _wrap_pool_connect(self, fn, connection)
   3367         except dialect.dbapi.Error as e:
   3368             if connection is None:
-> 3369                 Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
   3370                     e, dialect, self
   3371                 )

~/github-repos/dd_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(cls, e, dialect, engine)
   2201             util.raise_(newraise, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e)
   2202         elif should_wrap:
-> 2203             util.raise_(
   2204                 sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
   2205             )

~/github-repos/dd_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py in raise_(***failed resolving arguments***)
    209 
    210         try:
--> 211             raise exception
    212         finally:
    213             # credit to

~/github-repos/dd_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _wrap_pool_connect(self, fn, connection)
   3364         dialect = self.dialect
   3365         try:
-> 3366             return fn()
   3367         except dialect.dbapi.Error as e:
   3368             if connection is None:

~/github-repos/dd_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py in connect(self)
    325 
    326         """
--> 327         return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
    328 
    329     def _return_conn(self, record):

~/github-repos/dd_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py in _checkout(cls, pool, threadconns, fairy)
    892     def _checkout(cls, pool, threadconns=None, fairy=None):
    893         if not fairy:
--> 894             fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
    895 
    896             fairy._pool = pool

~/github-repos/dd_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py in checkout(cls, pool)
    491     @classmethod
    492     def checkout(cls, pool):
--> 493         rec = pool._do_get()
    494         try:
    495             dbapi_connection = rec.get_connection()

~/github-repos/dd_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py in _do_get(self)
    144             except:
    145                 with util.safe_reraise():
--> 146                     self._dec_overflow()
    147         else:
    148             return self._do_get()

~/github-repos/dd_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py in __exit__(self, type_, value, traceback)
     68             self._exc_info = None  # remove potential circular references
     69             if not self.warn_only:
---> 70                 compat.raise_(
     71                     exc_value,
     72                     with_traceback=exc_tb,

~/github-repos/dd_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py in raise_(***failed resolving arguments***)
    209 
    210         try:
--> 211             raise exception
    212         finally:
    213             # credit to

~/github-repos/dd_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py in _do_get(self)
    141         if self._inc_overflow():
    142             try:
--> 143                 return self._create_connection()
    144             except:
    145                 with util.safe_reraise():

~/github-repos/dd_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py in _create_connection(self)
    271         """Called by subclasses to create a new ConnectionRecord."""
    272 
--> 273         return _ConnectionRecord(self)
    274 
    275     def _invalidate(self, connection, exception=None, _checkin=True):

~/github-repos/dd_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py in __init__(self, pool, connect)
    386         self.__pool = pool
    387         if connect:
--> 388             self.__connect()
    389         self.finalize_callback = deque()
    390 

~/github-repos/dd_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py in __connect(self)
    689         except BaseException as e:
    690             with util.safe_reraise():
--> 691                 pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
    692         else:
    693             # in SQLAlchemy 1.4 the first_connect event is not used by

~/github-repos/dd_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py in __exit__(self, type_, value, traceback)
     68             self._exc_info = None  # remove potential circular references
     69             if not self.warn_only:
---> 70                 compat.raise_(
     71                     exc_value,
     72                     with_traceback=exc_tb,

~/github-repos/dd_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py in raise_(***failed resolving arguments***)
    209 
    210         try:
--> 211             raise exception
    212         finally:
    213             # credit to

~/github-repos/dd_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py in __connect(self)
    684         try:
    685             self.starttime = time.time()
--> 686             self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
    687             pool.logger.debug("Created new connection %r", connection)
    688             self.fresh = True

~/github-repos/dd_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py in connect(connection_record)
    572                     if connection is not None:
    573                         return connection
--> 574             return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
    575 
    576         creator = pop_kwarg("creator", connect)

~/github-repos/dd_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py in connect(self, *cargs, **cparams)
    596     def connect(self, *cargs, **cparams):
    597         # inherits the docstring from interfaces.Dialect.connect
--> 598         return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
    599 
    600     def create_connect_args(self, url):

~/github-repos/dd_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py in Connect(*args, **kwargs)
     92     """
     93     from .connections import Connection
---> 94     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
     95 
     96 from . import connections as _orig_conn

~/github-repos/dd_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py in __init__(self, host, user, password, database, port, unix_socket, charset, sql_mode, read_default_file, conv, use_unicode, client_flag, cursorclass, init_command, connect_timeout, ssl, read_default_group, compress, named_pipe, autocommit, db, passwd, local_infile, max_allowed_packet, defer_connect, auth_plugin_map, read_timeout, write_timeout, bind_address, binary_prefix, program_name, server_public_key)
    325             self._sock = None
    326         else:
--> 327             self.connect()
    328 
    329     def _create_ssl_ctx(self, sslp):

~/github-repos/dd_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py in connect(self, sock)
    586 
    587             self._get_server_information()
--> 588             self._request_authentication()
    589 
    590             if self.sql_mode is not None:

~/github-repos/dd_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py in _request_authentication(self)
    851 
    852         self.write_packet(data)
--> 853         auth_packet = self._read_packet()
    854 
    855         # if authentication method isn't accepted the first byte

~/github-repos/dd_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py in _read_packet(self, packet_type)
    674             if self._result is not None and self._result.unbuffered_active is True:
    675                 self._result.unbuffered_active = False
--> 676             packet.raise_for_error()
    677         return packet
    678 

~/github-repos/dd_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py in raise_for_error(self)
    221         errno = self.read_uint16()
    222         if DEBUG: print("errno =", errno)
--> 223         err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
    224 
    225     def dump(self):

~/github-repos/dd_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/err.py in raise_mysql_exception(data)
    105     if errorclass is None:
    106         errorclass = InternalError if errno < 1000 else OperationalError
--> 107     raise errorclass(errno, errval)

OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'xxx.xx.xx.51' (using password: YES)")
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

The ip in the error doesn't match the one in the connection string.
`engine.pool._pool.empty()` returns True. How is it still finding this other url?